# I have had some questions with sensitive information I accidentally posted—it won't let me delete the questions

Tags: support

I had posted two questions where I accidentally included sensitive data in my question - when I tried to remove the question it would not let me. Could someone please help me remove these two questions? I have edited out almost all the information for right now, but I want it deleted.

*[Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5.12 and my JUnit tests are throwing this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965370/upgrading-to-sprinboot-2-5-12-and-my-junit-tests-are-throwing-this-error)*

*[Upgrading to Spring Boot 2.5.12 and my JUnit tests are throwing this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71965370/upgrading-to-sprinboot-2-5-12-and-my-junit-tests-are-throwing-this-error)*